# How to modify TeX before it is processed by MathJax v3?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am attempting to do something similar to [this MathJax v2](https://github.com/shd101wyy/markdown-preview-enhanced/issues/722) startup hook, that modifies the TeX command before it is processed (every time before typesetting).

MathJax v3 does not have that Augment logic. Instead, there are [startup actions](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html#startup-action):

```js
window.MathJax = {

  // configuration...

  startup: {
    ready () {

      // MathJax is loaded, but not yet initialized
      // Get TeX here

      window.MathJax.startup.defaultReady();

      // MathJax is ready
    }
  }
}
```

But I didn't found anywhere in the documentation how to **get the TeX command** there, before it is processed. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a configuration for MathJax v3 that should do the trick, provided you are loading a component that has only one input processor.

```js
MathJax = {
  startup: {
    ready() {
      MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
      MathJax.startup.document.inputJax[0].preFilters.add(
        ({math}) => {
          if (math.display === false) {
            math.math = '\\displaystyle{' + math.math + '}';
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
};
```